# Executing a File Copying program written in C in terminal

Tags: c

This is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
        int c;
        c = getchar();
        while( c != EOF ){
                putchar(c);
        }
}
```

I have made another file named "AFile" using vim.

To display the contents of "AFile" using my program, what command do I write in the terminal?

Comment: What did you intent when you wrote that code? Your program copies input from `stdin` to `stdout`. That means you must feed your file in your program as `stdin`. Like `myprogram < AFile`

Comment: As you are working in a hosted environment, valid signatures for `main` are `int main(void)` or `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` or compatible. Implicit return type is no longer allowed since decades ago.

Comment: Generally you should first decide how you want to use your program, how you want to get input and then write the code accordingly. Doing it the other way around is a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

Your program reads from STDIN (fd 0), so you need to provide data at via stdin. In most shells, this can be done with the redirect operator `<`:

```
./yourprogram < inputfile
```

Another way would be using a pipe, but it is generally not recommended, because it needs to start an unnecessary second process:

```
cat inputfile | ./yourprogram
```